# Fling and scroll movements

Tags: java, android, gesture

My `View` implements `onGestureListener` to let me be informed when a gesture is done by the user, either if it is a scroll or a fling movement.

When the pointer is moved slowly on the screen, I receive `onScroll` events as expected.But when the pointer is moved faster, I get several `onScroll` events before getting the `onFling` event. As the `onFling` event passes the event associated with the "up" event, I suppose it is only triggered after the user takes his finger away from the screen.

Ans this causes a not natural behaviour for my application...

My question is : is it possible to suppress all the preceding `onScroll` events when the move executed by the user is clearly a fling movement?

Comment: You can create a flag. When first `onScroll` you get, make it `true`, and also return that in method. When `onFling` get finished, make it `false` again.

Comment: What is the purpose of this flag? I want to respond to the fling event and not to the preceding scroll events. How could I configure a flag to anticipate a fling event will arrive at the end of the move? My problem is I don't want to react to move events if a fling event is about to arrive.

Comment: Problem solved, but the solution doesn't look very clean : in the "onFling" function, I cancel every treatments realized in the "onScroll" function and I only take the "onFling" event into account if one of the velocity is greater than 1000 in absolute value.

Comment: Thats great.. Please post your answer and accept it.. so future Googler get benefit of it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, but the solution doesn't look very clean : in the "onFling" function, I cancel every treatments realized in the "onScroll" function and I only take the "onFling" event into account if one of the velocities is greater than 1000 in absolute value.

Comment: Can you post a piece of code so others know how did you do it?